# How to order a table before finding MAX() difference between two consecutive rows

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
     Events
----+------+-----
id  |start | end
----+------+-----
1   | 3    | 5
2   | 8    | 10
3   | 14   | 17
4   | 6    | 6
5   | 19   | 20
```

I would like to find the biggest number of empty days between two consecutive events.

**Desired result:**

> 3

This query return the `MAX()` gap, but I can't seem to find a way to **order** the result by the end column first:

```
SELECT MAX(empty)
FROM
( SELECT a.start-b.end-1 AS empty
 FROM 
        Reservations AS a, 
        Reservations AS b
WHERE a.id=b.id+1
GROUP BY b.end
ORDER BY b.end 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select max(start - prev_end) - 1 as diff
from (select t.*, lag(end) over (order by start) as prev_end
      from t
     ) t
where prev_end is not null;
```

Note:  This assumes that the periods are not overlapping, which is consistent with the data you have provided.

Comment: Thanks! Added a minus 1 to max(start - prev_end)-1 as diff, so it returns the number of empty days, not the difference.